# how to activate required fields on the wordpress registration form

Tags: wordpress, forms, field, registration, required

I customized the form in S2member. Fields marked "required" are only validated on the membership form and not the registration. I thought it was the same form? Any ideas? How do I get the fields (which are marked "required") to actually be required on the registration form?

Comment: you can't really post questions like this and expect an answer, it could be a custom form or the same form. you need to post the relevant code otherwise it would all be guess work. Start by looking at the template or the action of the form and find the code that handles the post. You might get lucky if you search the theme/plugin for the html input names.   Have a look at this for an idea of how it may have been done http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/how-to-display-wordpress-user-registration-form-in-front-end-of-the-website

Comment: It is the same form, when I change the fields in the s2member field options the changes are reflected on both pages. I noticed a comment about required fields which says that these fields are required once you are a member. Does that mean the first time registering they are not required because technically you are not a member yet?

Comment: depends on what the code is?